# Python: Lazy import of modules

Tags: python

I earlier researched lazy import of modules and found this way of doing it:

```
def some_funk():
    lazy_module = __import__("lazy_module")
    lazy_obj = lazy_module.LazyClass()
    lazy_obj.do_stuff()
```

Then I've seen some examples simply using:

```
def some_funk()
    import lazy_module
    lazy_obj = lazy_module.LazyClass()
    lazy_obj.do_stuff()
```

I prefer the later use and will rewrite my code to this.

But my question is if there is any difference between the two ways of doing lazy imports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between import and \_\_import\_\_ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401012/difference-between-import-and-import-in-python)

Comment: Your first example should be `lazy_module = __import__("lazy_module")` without `.lazy_module`.

Comment: Link a_guest provided contains valid response for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check [the documentation for import](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) out. `import lazy_module` is internally calling `__import__("lazy_module")`.

The lazy part of the import comes from both of them being done in a function, and not in the top of the class/script.